How to use new Capture Attribute node
Capture Attribute node in Blender 4.2LTS not looking the same as in Blender 3.3LTS and I am having no idea how to use this new Capture Attribute node.


The new Capture Attribute allows you to capture several attributes with a single node. Other than the Store Named Attribute where it makes sense to allow only a single source as input since you cannot store several attributes under a single name, it was always a bit uncomfortable having to use for example 4 Capture Attribute nodes just to capture 4 attributes on a single source geometry.
The new node has optional sockets and you do not have to switch the type manually, it adjusts automatically to whatever source you plug in, may it be float, vector, integer or whatever. After plugging something in the optional input, another optional input appears.
Sorry for my following bad example, this does not really make much sense to use a Capture Attribute node here but I guess it shows what the adavantage of the new one versus the old one is.
Here I am capturing 5 attributes on the geometry with the new node:

And here I am capturing the exact same 5 attributes with the old node:


I think a simple and practical example would be to use a capture attribute, capturing multiple outputs of a Raycast node, followed by multiple "Store Named Attribute" nodes. This makes sense because the attributes can be used elsewhere and showcases the performance improvement, because the raycast is done only once.

@MarkusvonBroady Well, my goal was mainly to show the difference between how the old node worked compared to the new one since the OP stated in the question having "no idea" how to use the new node. So I think my answer was already far too long. How the new node is an improvement or how to use it best goes a lot into answering opinion-based, so I would rather remove it from my answer instead of adding more examples. But feel free to add as many practical examples as you like.
